# Adding blank rows between each rows till end of rows with for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to design a for loop where excel would add a row in between row, take the rows count again and update the number of rows and again run another loop.
It should run the loop till all the rows are added in between each rows, so if row number was 7 ,updated rows should be 14.

Here is the code I am trying

```
 Sub df()


  For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 2


   Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Insert


  Next

End Sub
```

But with this the row number is frozen at 7 and it only runs the loop till 7th row, it doesn't ammend the row number after adding a row and run the loop based on new row number.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 1 To (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) * 2 Step 2
```

Comment: Thanks!! Great Idea!!
But I cant help wondering, isnt there anyway the number of rows could be continuously updated in the for loop funtion?